# Trigger ng-click in child element from parent element

Tags: angularjs

Hope you can help me with my problem. I have 2 cases:

**Case #1**: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abottoni/HsyWL/5/), I am trying to trigger the ng-click function of the child div, when I click in the parent div (an ng-click involved also in the parent), but I am getting an error ($apply already in progress).

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.pressOnParent = function ($event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log("Click over the parent");
        $("#child").trigger("click");
    }

    $scope.pressMe = function ($event) {
        $event.stopPropagation();
        console.log("I am being pressed");
    }
}
```

**Case #2**: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abottoni/HsyWL/6/), I am trying to do the same thing, but not using ng-click in the parent (but using jquery to attach the click event to it).

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $("#parent").on("click", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log("Click over the parent");
        $("#child").trigger("click");
    });

    $scope.pressMe = function ($event) {
        $event.stopPropagation();
        console.log("I am being pressed");
    }
}
```

My main goal is trying to get the Case #1 solved, because that is the case which is very alike to my final code in the project. Any ideas?

Thanks for the help you can give me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing DOM manipulation inside the controller considered a bad practice and should be avoided,so instead of using JQuery you can just call the child function inside the parent function.

**Example:**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.pressOnParent = function ($event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log("Click over the parent");
        $scope.pressMe($event);
    }

    $scope.pressMe = function ($event) {
        $event.stopPropagation();
        console.log("I am being pressed");
    }
}
```

edited your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/rMXrA/

Answer (score 2):

Your approach here is against Angular's declarative principles. Instead of locating the child div and clicking it within the parent callback you should be more explicit. Consider this example

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    var logger = function () {
        console.log("I am being pressed");
    };

    $scope.pressOnParent = function () {
        console.log('parent clicked');
        logger();
    };

    $scope.pressMe = function () {
        logger();
    };
}
```